# How to properly work with an ItemsSource on demand?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to bind a list of persons to a DataGrid control. 
The objects are loaded on demand, this means that initally I only have a List of IDs (int). In the DataGrid itself I want the objects (of type Person) with all their properties.

For that I used an IValueConverter that converts my `List<int>` to `List<Person>`.
I want to bind the SelectedItem to a property `int SelectedId`. I cannot simply bind to `Person`, since my Person class has no ID property. But with the value convertion the SelectedItem obviously is of type Person.

Should I initially load the objects in a Dictionary instead and bind that to the ItemsSource. SelectedItem would then be a KeyValuePair.

What other approaches are possible?

Comment: *For that I used an IValueConverter that converts my List to List* - Uhm wOot? Can you add some code, so that we get more detail information, please? Regarding your question, is your approach working? Or do you have specific problems with it?

Comment: can't you use Lazy<T> ? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/vstudio/dd642331.aspx

Comment: @DHN Sorry for the typos, I forgot to apply the code formatting. Right now I use a `Dictionary<int, Person>` as ItemsSource and a `KeyValuePair<int, Person>` as SelectedItem. This approach works, whereas I'm not sure if that's the common way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the best way to provide data in a list, is an `ObservableCollecion<T>`. I'm convinced that this is also the common way, but I've no source to prove it. So it's an IMHO statement.

It implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, so that the view is noticed about any changes (adding and removal of items). For more information pls refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).  If the item in the collection, in your case `Person`, is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the view will also be notified regarding changes of the items itself. Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) for more information.

So if I where you, I would put an id property into `Person` and load the whole collection into an `ObservableCollection`. If you cannot modify `Person` you could create a wrapper like

```
public class PersonVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public PersonVm(int id, Person person)
    {
        Id = id;
        Person = person;
    }
}
```

You will have to add the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` by yourself, if you want to have the notification feature of the items.

Btw, what I described here is a typical implementation of the MVVM pattern. It has definitely many advantages to implement a WPF application with it, but there are some disadvantages too. E.g. there is an overhead which may not be worth the effort in smaller projects. You can get an overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Comment: I prefer this solution over the above mentioned one since it follows the common MVVM pattern. The overhead is manageable, since the ViewModel is just a wrapper.